# Remove/add object into list

Tags: python

Can my coding work? The program should search for the hotel in the list, and if it returns None, I can add a new Hotel into the list.

I need help on the str part especially.

```
class Hotel:
    def __init__(self, name, address):
        self._name = name
        self._address = address

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @property
    def address(self):
        return self._address

    def __str__(self):
        return "Hotel Name: {} Address: {}".format(self._name, self._address)

class TransportServices:
    def __init__(self):
        self._hotels    = [] 
        #self._bookings  = [] # as you can see i have two other list in this class
        #self._drivers   = []

    def searchHotel(self, name):
        for h in self._hotels:
            if h.name == name:
                return h
        return None


    def addHotel(self, hotel):
        h = self.searchHotel(hotel)
        if h is None:
            self._hotels.append(hotel)
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def __str__(self):
        hotels = [str(h) for h in self._hotels]
        return "Hotels\n{} ".format(self._hotels) # need help here

def main():

   hotel = TransportServices()
   hotel.addHotel(Hotel("123", "ABC"))
   hotel.addHotel(Hotel("234", "QWE"))


   print(hotel)

main()
```

Comment: Have you executed it? Any errors?

Comment: it outputs [<__main__.Hotel object at 0x032C7950>, <__main__.Hotel object at 0x032C7970>]

Comment: you should use a name-indexed dictionary instead of a list.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your

```
def searchHotel(self, name):
    for h in self._hotels:
        if h.name == name:
            return h
    return None
```

method. You're comparing `h.name` to `name`, but `name` is not a string (like `h.name`), it's a `Hotel` object.

Try instead

```
def searchHotel(self, hotel):
    for h in self._hotels:
        if h.name == hotel.name:
            return h
    # return None is not necessary here, it's the default.
```

or else expect a string to be passed here and then in `addHotel` do:

```
h = self.searchHotel(hotel.name)
```

---

Note also that defining `__eq__` can be useful if two things should be logically the same. If any two Hotels share a name and an address, they should be the same hotel, so you can do

```
class Hotel:
    def __eq__(self, other: 'Hotel') -> bool:
        if not isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return False
        return (self.name, self.address) == (other.name, other.address)
```

This has the benefit of making `searchHotel` much easier.

```
def searchHotel(self, hotel):
    if hotel in self._hotels:
        return hotel
```

Answer (score 0):

it think because you are just printing the TransportServices object list, try to use the searchHotel function.

```
print(hotel.searchHotel("234"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your return statement.

Change

```
def __str__(self):
    hotels = [str(h) for h in self._hotels]
    return "Hotels\n{} ".format(self._hotels) # need help here
```

to

```
def __str__(self):
    hotels = [str(h) for h in self._hotels]
    return "Hotels\n{} ".format(hotels)
```